# Besse’s Formula for the Ricci Curvature (Corollary 7.33)

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a $G$-homogeneous manifold with isotropy group $K\subset G$ compact, $\mathfrak g$ the Lie algebra of $G$, and $\mathfrak k$ the Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ generated by $K$. Since $K$ is compact, we can use an averaging procedure to choose an $\mathrm{Ad}_G(K)$-invariant subspace $\mathfrak p$ so that $\mathfrak g$ is the direct sum $\mathfrak k\oplus \mathfrak p$. We identify $\mathfrak p$ with $T_xM$ and denote by $(\cdot,\cdot)$ the scalar product on $\mathfrak p$ corresponding to $g_x$.

Now, let $U:\mathfrak p\times \mathfrak p \rightarrow \mathfrak p$ be defined by
$$2(U(X,Y),Z) = ([Z,X]_\mathfrak p, Y) + (X,[Z,Y]_\mathfrak p)$$
for all $Z\in\mathfrak p$.

Then Arthur Besse derives (and I checked) in his book “Einstein Manifolds” p. 183 the following formula for the Riemann curvature

\begin{align}
g_x(R(X,Y)X,Y) = &-\frac34\left\vert[X,Y]_\mathfrak p\right\vert^2 -\frac12([X,[X,Y]_\mathfrak g]_\mathfrak p,Y)\\
            &-\frac12([Y,[Y,X]_\mathfrak g]_\mathfrak p, X) + \left\vert U(X,Y)\right\vert^2 - (U(X,X),U(Y,Y)). \tag{Theorem 7.30}
\end{align}

However, I’m having trouble deducing his next formula for the Ricci curvature from this. Letting $(X_i)$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathfrak p$, and $Z=\sum_i U(X_i,X_i)$, Besse writes:
\begin{align}
    r(X,X) = &-\frac 12\sum_i |[X,X_i]_\mathfrak p|^2 - \frac 12 \sum_i ([X,[X,X_i]_\mathfrak p]_\mathfrak p, X_i) - \sum_i([X,[X,X_i]_\mathfrak k]_\mathfrak p, X_i) \\ &+ \frac 14 \sum_{ij}([X_i,X_j]_\mathfrak p, X)^2 - ([Z,X]_\mathfrak p ,X), \tag{Corollary 7.33}
\end{align}

which is not what I get when I substitute Theorem 7.30 in

$$r(X,X) = \sum_i g_x(R(X,X_i)X,X_i).$$

In fact, the only term that I can identify in Corollary 7.33 from Theorem 7.30 is the last one, $([Z,X]_\mathfrak p, X)$ which equals $\sum_i (U(X,X),U(X_i,X_i))$. I am stuck at figuring out why the coefficient of the first term $-\frac 12 \sum_j |[X,X_i]_p|^2$ is not $-\frac34$,  from where $\frac14\sum_{i,j}([X_i,X_j]_\mathfrak p,X)^2$ appears and how to manipulate the term $\sum_i|U(X,X_i)|^2$.